# .Net 4.6 breaks XOR cipher pattern?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, bit-shift, xor, .net-4.6

In .NET 4.5 this cipher worked perfectly on 32 and 64 bit architecture. Switching the project to .NET 4.6 breaks this cipher completely in 64-bit, and in 32-bit there's an ***odd*** patch for the issue.

In my method "DecodeSkill", *SkillLevel is the only part that breaks on .NET 4.6.*
The variables used here are read from a network stream and are encoded.

DecodeSkill (Always returns the proper decoded value for *SkillLevel*)

```
    private void DecodeSkill()
    {
        SkillId = (ushort) (ExchangeShortBits((SkillId ^ ObjectId ^ 0x915d), 13) + 0x14be);
        SkillLevel = ((ushort) ((byte)SkillLevel ^ 0x21));
        TargetObjectId = (ExchangeLongBits(TargetObjectId, 13) ^ ObjectId ^ 0x5f2d2463) + 0x8b90b51a;
        PositionX = (ushort) (ExchangeShortBits((PositionX ^ ObjectId ^ 0x2ed6), 15) + 0xdd12);
        PositionY = (ushort) (ExchangeShortBits((PositionY ^ ObjectId ^ 0xb99b), 11) + 0x76de);
    }
```

ExchangeShortBits

```
    private static uint ExchangeShortBits(uint data, int bits)
    {
        data &= 0xffff;
        return (data >> bits | data << (16 - bits)) & 65535;
    }
```

DecodeSkill (*Patched* for .NET 4.6 32-bit, notice "var patch = SkillLevel")

```
    private void DecodeSkill()
    {
        SkillId = (ushort) (ExchangeShortBits((SkillId ^ ObjectId ^ 0x915d), 13) + 0x14be);
        var patch = SkillLevel = ((ushort) ((byte)SkillLevel ^ 0x21));
        TargetObjectId = (ExchangeLongBits(TargetObjectId, 13) ^ ObjectId ^ 0x5f2d2463) + 0x8b90b51a;
        PositionX = (ushort) (ExchangeShortBits((PositionX ^ ObjectId ^ 0x2ed6), 15) + 0xdd12);
        PositionY = (ushort) (ExchangeShortBits((PositionY ^ ObjectId ^ 0xb99b), 11) + 0x76de);
    }
```

Assigning the variable as SkillLevel, in 32-bit only, will cause SkillLevel to always be the correct value. Remove this patch, and the value is always incorrect. In 64-bit, this is always incorrect even with the patch.

I've tried using MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization and MethodImplOptions.NoInlining on the decode method thinking it would make a difference.

Any ideas to what would cause this?

Edit:
I was asked to give an example of input, good output, and bad output.
This is from an actual usage scenario, values were sent from the client and properly decoded by the server using the "patch" on .NET 4.6.

Input:

```
ObjectId = 1000001

TargetObjectId = 2778236265
PositionX = 32409
PositionY = 16267
SkillId = 28399
SkillLevel = 8481
```

Good Output

```
TargetObjectId = 0
PositionX = 302
PositionY = 278
SkillId = 1115
SkillLevel = 0
```

Bad Output

```
TargetObjectId = 0
PositionX = 302
PositionY = 278
SkillId = 1115
SkillLevel = 34545
```

Edit#2:

I should include this part, definitely an important part to this.

EncodeSkill (***Timestamp*** is Environment.TickCount)

```
     private void EncodeSkill()
    {
        SkillId = (ushort) (ExchangeShortBits(ObjectId - 0x14be, 3) ^ ObjectId ^ 0x915d);
        SkillLevel = (ushort) ((SkillLevel + 0x100*(Timestamp%0x100)) ^ 0x3721);
        Arg1 = MathUtils.BitFold32(SkillId, SkillLevel);
        TargetObjectId = ExchangeLongBits(((TargetObjectId - 0x8b90b51a) ^ ObjectId ^ 0x5f2d2463u), 19);
        PositionX = (ushort) (ExchangeShortBits((uint) PositionX - 0xdd12, 1) ^ ObjectId ^ 0x2ed6);
        PositionY = (ushort) (ExchangeShortBits((uint) PositionY - 0x76de, 5) ^ ObjectId ^ 0xb99b);
    }
```

BitFold32

```
    public static int BitFold32(int lower16, int higher16)
    {
        return (lower16) | (higher16 << 16);
    }
```

ExchangeLongBits

```
    private static uint ExchangeLongBits(uint data, int bits)
    {
        return data >> bits | data << (32 - bits);
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input data, good output, and bad output?

Comment: Sure, give me 2-3 minutes.

Comment: I've added some examples of good and bad output from client input.

Comment: Also added the encoding method.

Comment: The EncodeSkill you've posted wouldn't actually compile if I'm not mistaken. Your field/property is named `SkillID` and `EncodeSkill` references `SkillId`. Is this pseudocode?

Comment: Typo actually. Sorry, fixed the naming.

Comment: Where is SkillLevel initialized?

Comment: SkillLevel is initialized by the client side, the value is taken from an ini datastore. These values range from 0-9 typically.

Comment: @Scotty Can you post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that actually reproduces the problem instead? It would be helpful to have something you can actually compile instead of having to analyze this pseudocode.

Comment: There is no undefined behavior in these operations in the C# language. The result is precisely defined. No matter what it is it should always be the same. This is the 3rd JIT bug I hear about after launch of .NET 4.6. Please report it on GitHub at the CoreCLR project.

Comment: Do you see the bad output in .NET 4.6 even if you build in "Debug" mode, i.e. without optimizations? Or is there no difference between "Debug" and "Release"?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I did my testing in Debug mode on .NET 4.6. I can see the issue occurring.

Comment: Debug mode, if you use var x = SkillLevel, the value will be correct. Release mode, there's nothing you can do to correct the value. But Asad provided a work-around for this issue.

Comment: @Asad Then I speculate if the problem is with the new Roslyn-based C# compiler in which case the "bug" happens already at compile-time. Or if this is a problem with the jitter, like other bugs recently found with the .NET runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code I've come up with that I think is analogous to your actual scenario:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dc = new Decoder();
        dc.DecodeSkill();
        Debug.Assert(dc.TargetObjectId == 0m && dc.PositionX == 302 && dc.PositionY == 278 && dc.SkillId == 1115 && dc.SkillLevel == 0);
    }
}

class Decoder
{
    public uint ObjectId = 1000001;
    public uint TargetObjectId = 2778236265;
    public ushort PositionX = 32409;
    public ushort PositionY = 16267;
    public ushort SkillId = 28399;
    public ushort SkillLevel = 8481;

    public void DecodeSkill()
    {
        SkillId = (ushort)(ExchangeShortBits((SkillId ^ ObjectId ^ 0x915d), 13) + 0x14be);
        SkillLevel = ((ushort)((byte)(SkillLevel) ^ 0x21));
        TargetObjectId = (ExchangeLongBits(TargetObjectId, 13) ^ ObjectId ^ 0x5f2d2463) + 0x8b90b51a;
        PositionX = (ushort)(ExchangeShortBits((PositionX ^ ObjectId ^ 0x2ed6), 15) + 0xdd12);
        PositionY = (ushort)(ExchangeShortBits((PositionY ^ ObjectId ^ 0xb99b), 11) + 0x76de);
    }

    private static uint ExchangeShortBits(uint data, int bits)
    {
        data &= 0xffff;
        return (data >> bits | data << (16 - bits)) & 65535;
    }

    public static int BitFold32(int lower16, int higher16)
    {
        return (lower16) | (higher16 << 16);
    }

    private static uint ExchangeLongBits(uint data, int bits)
    {
        return data >> bits | data << (32 - bits);
    }
}
```

You're XORing 8481 with 33. That's 8448, which is what I see on my machine. Assuming, `SkillLevel` is a `ushort`, I think what is going on is that you're expecting the cast to `byte` to truncate `SkillLevel` so that all that is left is the last 8 bits, but this is not happening, so when you cast back to `ushort` the higher order bits are still there.

If you want to reliably truncate all digits after the lower 8, you need to bitmask it like so:

```
SkillLevel = ((ushort) ((SkillLevel & 255) ^ 0x21));
```

EDIT:

I have a suspicion that this has something to do with numeric promotions from operators. The `^` operator, when applied to a `byte` *or* an `ushort` and an `int`, will promote both operands to `int`, since implicit conversions exist from both possible types of the first operand to `int`. It seems like what is happening is that the **explicit** conversion from `ushort` to `byte` , which would cause truncation, is being skipped. Now you just have two `int`s, which when XORed, then truncated back to `ushort`, keep their higher order bits.

Comment: So the cast to byte works as he expects on some machines (including my 32-bit 4.5 one) but not under 4.6?  Did something in the spec change? or did an implementation behavior change?

Comment: This is bogus. There is no undefined behavior in these operations in the C# language. The result is precisely defined. No matter what it is it should always be the same on all CLR's of the last 10 years.

Comment: Also, where's his 34545 coming from?

Comment: Hero! Thank you :) Bitmasking was the answer, apparently reboxing the value as byte changed since .NET 4.5-4.6

Comment: @MarkPeters I'm not really seeing any difference in behavior on .NET 4.5 vs .NET 4.6. In both cases, it works in 32 bit, gives me 8448 on 64 bit. However, this could be because .NET 4.6 is an in place upgrade to .NET 4.5. Regarding `34545`, I haven't been able to reproduce this.

Comment: @usr The `ushort` type isn't CLS compliant, so I'm not sure what good bringing the C# language specification into this does.

Comment: @Scotty "apparently reboxing the value as byte changed since .NET 4.5-4.6" -- well now, that's something that shouldn't have changed and might break other things as well. Sounds to me like you should report this to the CoreCLR team on GitHub.

Comment: @Asad the C# spec defines what ushort does exactly. Truncating casts are also defined to the last bit.

Comment: @usr If you're familiar with it, could you please point to the section of the specification where this behavior is defined?

Comment: The C# Language Specification has a section [Explicit numeric conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691289.aspx). This link goes to an old version. You should find the newest version of the C# Language Specification elsewhere. Check if you have a folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 13.0\VC#\Specifications\1033` or similar.

Comment: @usr I dug through the spec and have a new theory. What do you think?

Comment: Plausible. A broken optimization that skips a truncating cast.